# write awk command which find the no. of delimiter in a file

Tags: unix, awk, delimiter

I have to write a awk command to find the no. of delimiter in a file.

I tried this :

```
awk -F '|'  'NF >0 {print NR, $0} ' file_name
```

but its not working

Comment: Hello! Could you specify an example of behavior you want and what you expect? What do you mean by not working ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to know number of total fields in a line then you could use steffen's code in case you need to know number of delimiters in current line then you could use following.

```
awk -F'|'  'NF{print (NF-1), $0} ' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`NR` is the number of records, you're searching for `NF`, the number of fields:

```
awk -F '|'  'NF >0 {print NF, $0} ' file_name
```